# Is there a CDK or CloudFormation construct to import an entire DNS zone transfer?

Tags: typescript, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

All of our DNS entries currently reside outside of AWS.  We would like to migrate to Route53, but as part of this, we would like to build a redeployable method of standing up the entire zone from scratch, including creating entries for non-AWS resources.  So far, I have not identified a bulk transfer option outside of the AWS Console.  Instead, my TypeScript CDK code currently iterates over a list of records and creates each one individually.  This would be fine, except I've surpassed the number of resources allowed in a stack.  Before I go to the trouble of refactoring this to generate multiple stacks and avoid the resource limit, does a method to bulk import via code exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Route53 record is its own CloudFormation resource, so you can't hack around that, as long as you're using CloudFormation to create them. There's a [`RecordSetGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-recordsetgroup.html) resource ([Cloudformation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-recordsetgroup.html)), but each record in the group is still represented by a `RecordSet` resource.

Now, a hacky workaround would be to use a custom resource - this is a Lambda that you implement that does pretty much anything, including creating an arbitrary amount of records.

Check out the [custom resources CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html) for details.